# Getting the_excerpt to link to child pages

Tags: excerpt

I'm using the Twentyeleven `'continue reading'` function for my excerpts

```
function twentyeleven_continue_reading_link() {
return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . __( 'Read more', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</a>';
}
```

This works fine until I pull it in to link to a child page. The 'Read More' links to the Parent page only.

How can I get it to pick up the permalink of my child pages as well?

Comment: An excerpt is usually something that will be displayed for posts, not pages, except in heavily customised themes. Can you give more of a context of what you are trying to do, maybe just give us an example of your attempted use of the function to do your intended job